# Using oracle sdo_geometry with EntityFramework 6.0 and .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

This [article](http://blog.devart.com/using-entity-framework-spatials-with-oracle-spatial-and-sharpmap.html) states that EF 5.0+ and .NET 4.5 fully support spatial types like oracle sdo_geometry. But when I try to import a table with a geometry I get this error:

```
Data type 'sdo_geometry' not supported by .NET Framework
```

I've already checked and I'm using .NET 4.5 in my project compiler options. So what am I missing?

Comment: Which database connector are you using? The article you linked is about dotConnect data provider for EF.

Comment: I'm using oracle 11g. Now I'm tryng the trial version of dotConnect but I thought spatial data was supported by .NET and EF 5 without using another commercial tool

Comment: EF _does_ support spatial types, but it's also up to the data provider to implement it correctly. A data provider for SQL Server is built-in and shipped by default, but for other databases, you need a third party tool to make the link between the generic implementation of EF and the details that are specific to a database.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the SDO_GEOMETRY types are not currently supported in the ODP.NET driver. Neither can you use User Defined Types (UDT) yet, as you could in the unmanaged driver to process the geometries.

Here are a few ideas for work arounds:

1. Use the managed driver in parallel with the unmanaged driver (not great idea)
2. Use an alternate data provider (e.g. dotConnect) as commented
3. Use raw SQL and the Oracle [SDO_UTIL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_util.htm) package

   ```
   // result = "POINT(30.1 - 21.9)"
   DbRawSqlQuery<string> result = 
     dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(COORDS) ...");
   ```
4. A variation on the above point, but use command interception

   ```
   public class MyDbCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor 
   {
     public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
     {
       if (command.CommandText.Contains("__MARKER__"))
       {
         // Do some funky text replacement
       }
     }
     ...
   }

   public partial class MyEntity 
   {
     [Column("__MARKER__COLUMNAME"]
     public string Coord { get; set; }
   }

   // Before you run the query:
   MyDbCommandInterceptor interceptor = new MyDbCommandInterceptor();
   DBInterception.Add(interceptor);
   ```